# Why does this Prolog code not write my list to a file?

Tags: prolog

The following rules should write my List to a stream associated with a file, but instead it is a never ending stream of incomprehensible characters. Help.

```
writeListToFile(List, File) :- open(File, write, Stream),
                   \+ writeListToStream(Stream, List),
                   close(Stream).

writeListToStream(Stream, List) :- member(Element, List),
                   write(Stream, Element),
                   write(Stream, ' '),
                   fail.
```

This occurs even when using a simple list like

```
List = ['a', 'b'].
```

Upon executing

```
writeListToFile(List, 'output.txt').
```

my SWI-Prolog does not respond and I see the file filling up with endless lines of

> "_G889 _G892 _G895 _G898 _G901 _G904 _G907 _G910 _G913 _G916 _G919
>   _G922 _G925 _G928 _G931 _G934 _G937 _G940 _G943 _G946 _G949 _G952 _G955 _G958 _G961 _G964 _G967 _G970 _G973 _G976 _G979 _G982 _G985 _G988 _G991 _G994 _G997 _G1000 _G1003 _G1006 _G1009 _G1012 _G1015 _G1018"

etc.

Comment: Could you need to do `write(Stream, Element),`?

Comment: Yep. You need `write(Stream, Element)` and `write(Stream, ' ')`. Otherwise, how does `write` know what stream you're writing to? The default is standard output. You may have noticed your list being written to the screen when you run `writeListToFile/2`.

Comment: Oops that was what I did originally, I was just tired of having to cancel the process in task manager, it still doesn't stop execution.

Comment: When you execute `writeListToFile(List, 'output.txt')` you're writing an uninstantiated list, which looks like `[_, _, _, ...]`, a list with an undefined number elements with no instantiation. So that's why you get what you see. Try `List = [a,b,c], writeListToFile(List, 'output.txt').`. If you are entering `List = [a,b,c]` on a separate line at the prompt with a period, then that query completes and `List` is no longer instantiated if you enter `writeListToFile(List, 'output.txt')` on a separate line.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much @lurker !

Comment: @lurker You may want to turn that into an actual answer. I would vote it up.